# Why is my function using Python time limited in input value magnatude?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a function that tests the command `time` in python. The function should take `m,n`as a parameters and calculates `MODEXP(a,e,p)` where p is prime generator at most `2^m` and e in first case is `2^n` and in second case is `2^(n-1)` and a is random positive integer less than p.

Here is my code:

```
import random
def question_3(m,n):
    list = []
    for i in xrange(2,2**m):
        flag=True
        for num in list:
            if(i%num==0):
                flag=False
        if(flag):
            list.append(i)
            p = choice(list)
            a = randint(1,int(p)-1) 
            e = pow(2,n)
    return pow(a, e, p)

    time t = question_3(5,5) #non-Python syntax.
```

The problem is that this function cant work with `m` and `n` greater than `20` for both of them and i dont know why.

Comment: Is this your actual code? I don't think `time t = question_3(5,5)` is valid Python syntax.

Comment: actually i am doing it in sage and it is valid in it

Comment: In what way is your code not working?  Do you get an error or does it just seem to hang?  With a for-loop running over a million times (2^m with m => 20)  it is not too surprising that the code may appear to hang.  Also once you hit m ~ 30 your list will start to reach the maximum possible size (if you are on a 32-bit machine).

Comment: when i write time for example time t = question_3(100,100) it will hang and it don't give me any error but i don't know the reason for this

Comment: The problem is that apparently you don't know how to count. Do you understand how big is 2**100? It's 1267650600228229401496703205376. Whatever the code is doing (not clear to me) it's not going to finish anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

You code runs fine on my box without hanging. As others have pointed out, it is O(2**n), hence the run time grows exponentially. Here my timing:

```
m = n = 2; time needed:  1.90734863281e-05
m = n = 3; time needed:  1.50203704834e-05
m = n = 4; time needed:  2.21729278564e-05
m = n = 5; time needed:  4.38690185547e-05
m = n = 6; time needed:  9.41753387451e-05
m = n = 7; time needed:  0.000232934951782
m = n = 8; time needed:  0.000643014907837
m = n = 9; time needed:  0.00198698043823
m = n = 10; time needed:  0.00656795501709
m = n = 11; time needed:  0.0229339599609
m = n = 12; time needed:  0.082200050354
m = n = 13; time needed:  0.299206972122
m = n = 14; time needed:  1.09857010841
m = n = 15; time needed:  4.06366610527
m = n = 16; time needed:  15.0994331837
m = n = 17; time needed:  56.4191129208
```

For m = n = 100, it would take roughly 1.3 * 10^49 seconds.

Comment: ok, now when i tried to make m=n=100 it gives me this OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Comment: Apparently your python interpreter doesn't support arbitrary length integers, (which might be against the spec)...

Comment: @Hyperboreus: `xrange` uses a C long internally. In Python 3 `range` uses python abitrary-precision ints.

Comment: @Wooble Thank you Wooble. I wasn't aware of that. Is this part of the spec of py2.x or is it an implementation detail of cython?

Comment: it's just cpython. You can assume that Jython doesn't use C ints for anything :)